Issue with Unresponsive Apps on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat on my new ThinkPad E16 machine, and I've been encountering a frustrating issue with certain applications becoming unresponsive and losing focus. This issue occurs primarily with apps like Slack, Docker, Zoom, and even Microsoft Edge browser at times. For example, in Slack, I often find that I can't click anywhere within the app, though typing still works. Additionally, clicking on these apps sometimes causes them to minimize and send another app to the foreground unexpectedly.
This problem has become particularly problematic during Zoom meetings, where I've been unable to click on essential buttons like the unmute option. Interestingly, I can still move these apps between workspaces, and I'm using two monitors in my setup.
I've installed these apps primarily through Snap and Flatpak. Has anyone else experienced similar issues with applications becoming unresponsive and losing focus on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS? And if so, are there any known solutions or workarounds to address this problem?

Install these apps as .deb files, and let us know if the issue persists.

Hey @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried that and it is not working. The problem persists a lot more on VSCode. I found out something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78449949/vs-code-isnt-focused-when-i-click-on-it-on-my-ubuntu-machine

How much RAM do you have?
